# If a specific string is not in the file, I'm trying to report a message. I keep getting the same message

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm reading a text file. If a specific string is not in the file, I'm trying to report a message. I keep getting the same message over again, or, not at all depending on where I put it.

I have moved this (code just above counter++; near the bottom)
"else lbOne.Items.Add(txtID.Text + " does not exist.");" around to every conceivable line with no luck. I know just enough to be dangerous, so could use some help with this.

```
    if (rButtonFind.Checked)
        {
            int counter = 0;
            string line;
            System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"F:\Quality\CMM Fixtures\fixtures.txt");

            if (new FileInfo(@"F:\09 Quality\CMM Fixtures\fixtures.txt").Length == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There is no data in the file to search." + "\n" + "There must be at least one fixture" + "\n" + " to not see this message.");
            }

                while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if (line.Contains(txtID.Text))
                    {
                        lbOne.Items.Add(line);
                    }
                    else
                    lbOne.Items.Add(txtID.Text + " does not exist.");
                    counter++;
                }           

                file.Close();                
            }         
        }
```

As I said, it either lists the "does not exist" message many times, or not at all.

Comment: Do you need to know if every line does not contain `txtID.Text` or do you need to know if only one of them doesn't? The way you're written the code it looks like you're trying to identify any line that doesn't contain `txtID.Text`. Additionally, you've been careful about using `{` and `}` in every block except for one. You should tag your question with the language you're using. A good to follow, is to add an [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your questions and include the inputy, the output your expect, and the output you got.

Comment: I need to read the entire file, and ensure the string does not exist. For further information, the string being searched for will only exist on one line of a text file, but it could exist multiple times. I just need to know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by playing with Jeff's code. By simply switching the bool declaration to true, and then the if found to "!true", and removing the break, it works as it should. I would not have gotten this without Jeffs help. I **double asterisked** the changes I made to Jeffs code that made it work.

```
                    bool found = **true**;
                    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line.Contains(txtID.Text))
                        {
                            lbOne.Items.Add(line);
                            found = **!true**;                            
                        }
                        counter++;                       
                    }

                    if (**found**)
                    {
                        lbOne.Items.Add(txtID.Text + " does not exist.");                        
                    }
                    file.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to know only if the file contains at least one occurrence of the string, then this is the code you need. But you also need to better defend against the file not existing.

I don't know if `counter` is supposed to be a count of lines read or if it's supposed to indicate a count of times the string is not found. I just assumed it's a count of times the string is not found. But regardless, the scope of `counter` is within the `if` block and so there's no use for it unless you intend to do something with it later, in which case you'll have to change its scope.

```
if (rButtonFind.Checked) {
   int counter = 0;
   string line;
   string filename = @"F:\Quality\CMM Fixtures\fixtures.txt";
   System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);
   if (new FileInfo(filename).Length == 0) {
      MessageBox.Show("There is no data in the file to search." + "\n" + "There must be at least one fixture" + "\n" + " to not see this message.");
   } else {
      bool found = false;
      while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
         if (line.Contains(txtID.Text)) {
            lbOne.Items.Add(line);
            found = true;
            break;
         }
      }
      if (!found) {
         lbOne.Items.Add(txtID.Text + " does not exist.");
         counter++;
      }
   }
   file.Close();
}
```

Comment: I see I missed many things. This is my first time posting here. This is C#. The counter is reading through a text file. For each instance of the string found, it reports that string to a list box. If it does not find an instance of the string, it just reports "does not exist".

If it finds three instances, it will look like this in a list box, for example:

C0004 1A4
C0004 2B2
C0004 3C1

If it finds nothing, it will report to a list box.

C0004 does not exist.

As I said, rest of the code works fine. I just cannot get it to properly report when it does not find a string.

Comment: If `counter` is really `numberOfLinesRead` and you're not reporting the number of lines read or the line where `txtID.Text` is found, then just remove all references to `counter` and its definition.

Comment: @Todd What is the meaning of `lbOne`? Your use of it is confusing.

Comment: I used the code you provided, and it now reports correctly that something does not exist, but it only reports the first instance of multiple strings. When I remove the break though, it then reports both the string and "does not exist" simultaneously.

Comment: lbOne is just the name of the listbox. Do I not need the counter to report all instances of the string?

Comment: @Todd A list of what?

Comment: The listbox is empty. It's just reporting what is found in the text file.

Comment: I will try to reconstruct this question Jeff. Apparently I've not done a good job of asking it! Thank you for your help today though.

Comment: @Todd A list of what? You said the string appears on one line only but that it might appear more than once on a line. Are you indicating that you want one item in the listbox for each occurrence on the line? If so, how much context surrounding each occurrence do you want? Modify your original question showing a couple of lines (one line including the search string in two places and another line with no occurrences). Then add a list of what you want your listbox text to look like.